# Android MediaPlayer, VideoView rtsp www authentication issue

Tags: android, media-player, rtsp, android-videoview

Android VideoView works when I disable rtsp authentication from server side. But when authentication is enabled the VideoView fails to play the live stream.
Also tried

`rtsp://username:password@host:port/file.sdp =>`doesn't work.

But `rtsp://host:port/file.sdp =>` Works when authentication is disable.

I have been working on this issue from past 2 weeks but did not find much help on this.
Or else if any open source rtsp player for android that support authentication will do.
Or any other workaround I can use to achieve this.

Guys please please help.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, did you got any solution for this? I think the android RTSP client is not supporting the authentication feature at all. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class support [several media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

But regarding the RTSP protocol, the authentification is not supported.
You can find an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10703) on the android project and an other [interesting post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-platform/d3t-qBztfTw) about the problem.